# How to implement Guava cache to store and get different types of objects?

Tags: java, generics, caching, design-patterns, guava

Right now my cache looks like the following:

```java
public class TestCache {

    private LoadingCache<String, List<ObjectABC>> cache;

    TestCache() {
        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(25)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, List<ObjectABC>>(
                ) {
                    @Override
                    public List<ObjectABC> load(String key) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return addCache(key);
                    }

                });
    }

    private List<ObjectABC> addCache(String key) {
    final JoiObjectMapper mapper = new JoiObjectMapper();

        final Collection<File> allConfigFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(key), null, true);
        final List<ObjectABC> configsList = new ArrayList<>();

        allConfigFiles.forEach(configFile -> {
            try {
                     configsList.add(mapper.readValue(configFile, new TypeReference<ObjectABC>() {
                      }));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        return configsList;
    }

    public List<ObjectABC> getEntry(String key) {
         try {
            return cache.get(key);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new NonRetriableException(String.format(
                    "Exception occured while trying to get data from cache for the key : {} Exception: {}",
                    key.toString(), e));
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, when I pass a `String key` (which is path to a local folder) it takes all the files present in that location and maps them to `ObjectABC` using `ObjectMapper`.

Now my problem is that I want to instead have a generic loading cache like
`LoadingCache<String, List<Object>>`.

And I want to map files in different folders to different Objects, e.g. map files in */root/Desktop/folder1* to `List<ObjectABC>` and map files in */root/Desktop/folder2* to `List<ObjectDEF>` and be able to store and retrieve that information from the cache.

How can I pass to the cache the information of which object to use for mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom class wrapping a `LoadingCache<Key<?>, Object>` like that:

```
class HeterogeneousCache {

    private final LoadingCache<Key<?>, Object> cache;

    public <T> T get(Key<T> key) throws ExecutionException {
        return key.getType().cast(cache.get(key));
    }
}

@Value // provides constructor, getters, equals, hashCode
class Key<T> {

    private final String identifier;
    private final Class<T> type;
}
```

(I used Lombok's [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) annotation for simplicity)

Of course, this is just a stub and you might need to adapt this to your needs. The main problem might be that you can't get a `Class<List<ObjectABC>>` - you can only get a `Class<List>`. The easiest way out of this is to wrap the `List<ObjectABC>` in some custom type. The harder way (not recommended) is to use Guava's [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained).

---

*Attribution*: This answer is based on the post by [Frank Appel](https://www.codeaffine.com/author/fappel/) entitled [How to Map Distinct Value Types Using Java Generics](https://www.codeaffine.com/2015/03/04/map-distinct-value-types-using-java-generics/), which itself is based on [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch)'s [typesafe hetereogeneous containers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8) from *Effective Java*.

---

## *Edit*: A Complete Solution

Since the OP wants `List<T>` as result, and since he needs instances of `TypeReference<T>`, I replaced `Class<T>` with `TypeReference<T>` in `Key<T>`:

```
@Value // provides constructor, getters, equals, hashCode
class Key<T> {
    private final String identifier;
    private final TypeReference<T> typeReference;
}
```

Here's how `CustomHeterogeneousCache` looks now:

```
class CustomHeterogeneousCache {

    private final LoadingCache<Key<?>, List<?>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maximumSize(25)
            .build(CacheLoader.from(this::computeEntry));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> getEntry(Key<T> key) {
        return (List<T>) cache.getUnchecked(key);
    }

    private <T> List<T> computeEntry(Key<T> key) {
        final JoiObjectMapper mapper = new JoiObjectMapper();
        final Collection<File> allConfigFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(key.getIdentifier()), null, true);
        return allConfigFiles.stream()
                .map(configFile -> {
                    try {
                        return mapper.readValue(configFile, key.getTypeReference());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Since implementations of `TypeReference` do not have value semantics, the user must make sure that every `Key` is created once, and then only referenced, e.g.:

```
class Keys {
    public static final Key<ObjectABC> ABC = new Key<>("/root/Desktop/folder1", new TypeReference<ObjectABC>() {
    });
    public static final Key<ObjectDEF> DEF = new Key<>("/root/Desktop/folder2", new TypeReference<ObjectDEF>() {
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a doubt:
How do i use the 'type' while mapping a file to the required class. e.g. it does not allow me to change the following line
mapper.readValue(configFile, new TypeReference<ObjectABC>() {}) to 
mapper.readValue(configFile, new TypeReference<key.getType()>() {})

Comment: @PankajVatsa Sorry for a late reply. See my edit, which contains the complete solution.